# Example of a finite projective plane which is not a translation plane

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples, projective-geometry, finite-geometry

I've been studying finite projective geometry for several weeks and I came across the fact that the most studied planes are the translation planes. Is there any known example (of minimum order if possible) of a finite projective plane which is not a translation plane ?

Answer (score 3):

All projective planes of order $\leq 8$ are Desarguesian (and hence translation planes).
Up to isomorphism, there are four projective planes of order $9$, among them the Desarguesian plane and a single further translation plane.
Hence the smallest order of a projective plane which is not a translation plane is $9$, and up to isomorphism, there are two such planes.